# Angular FormControl Placeholder will not update dynamically with passed value

Tags: angular

I hope someone can help me, I'm at a bit of a blocking point here.
I am pretty new to Angular so please excuse my mistakes.

I am trying to update my placeholder text for an input FormControl as follows:

I have the following component class:

```
export class EditFormComponent {

namePlaceholder:String="";

  restaurantForm = new FormGroup({
    id: new FormControl(''),
    name: new FormControl(''),
    address: new FormControl(''),
    specialities: new FormControl(''),
    details: new FormControl('')
  });

 passObjectValues(restaurant: RestaurantsPost) {
    this.restaurantForm.setValue({ id: restaurant.id, name: restaurant.name, address: restaurant.addressId });
    this.namePlaceholder=restaurant.name + "test";
    console.log(this.restaurantForm);
    console.log(this.namePlaceholder);
  }
```

**HTML** component looks like so:

```
<form class="container-card" [formGroup]="restaurantForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(restaurantForm)">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label style="color: white; font-weight:500;"for="name">
            Name
        </label>
        <input 
            formControlName="name"
            id="name" 
            type="text" 
            class="form-control"
            [placeholder]="namePlaceholder" // doesn't work
            placeholder="{{namePlaceholder}}"> // doesn't work 
    </div>
```

I assume this is happening because I do not create an instance of my EditFormComponent but I am instead calling a method from the class, and thus the value I pass are not registered at compile-time when building my form-group.

I have also tried calling a constructor, instead of calling my passObjectValues() method, but this is a challenge of its own.

My **constructor** is like so:

```
constructor(editedRestaurant:RestaurantsPost) {

    this.templateRestaurant=editedRestaurant;
```

My **RestaurantPost** Object:

```
@Injectable()
export class RestaurantsPost {


    id: String;
    name: String;
    addressId: String;
    specialitiesId: String;
    detailsId: String;
    bookingId: String;

    constructor(id:String,name:String,addressId:String,specialitiesId: String,detailsId: String,bookingId: String){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.addressId=addressId;
        this.specialitiesId=specialitiesId;
        this.detailsId=detailsId;
        this.bookingId=bookingId
    }
}
```

**app.module.ts** looks like so:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    RestaurantComponent,
    EditFormComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    DemoMaterialModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  providers: [
    HttpErrorHandler,
    HttpClientModule,
    String
  ],
  bootstrap: [
    AppComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Browser throws this error :

```
>    main.ts:12 Error: Can't resolve all parameters for String: (?).
>     at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory (core.js:11428)
>     at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (core.js:11418)
>     at providerToFactory (core.js:11461)
>     at providerToRecord (core.js:11448)
>     at R3Injector.processProvider (core.js:11346)
>     at core.js:11332
>     at core.js:4129
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
>     at deepForEach (core.js:4129)
>     at R3Injector.processInjectorType (core.js:11332)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

**UPDATE :**

I managed to fix my problem by adding a binding to the field that opens my edit-form:

```
<edit-form [selectedRestaurant] = "selectedRestaurant" *ngIf="editPressed"></edit-form>
```

When I click the "edit" button I am calling a method that is saving the value of the current object to the selectedRestaurant.

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="editRestaurant(restaurant,!editPressed)">
```

In my restaurant.component i have this method that saves the restaurant for which i press the edit button and the boolean field is used to toggle the edit-form:

```
editRestaurant(passedRestaurant: Restaurants, isActivated:boolean): void {
        this.selectedRestaurant=passedRestaurant;
        this.editPressed=isActivated;

}
```

This is bound to an object in my edit-form component:

```
@Input('selectedRestaurant') selectedRestaurant: Restaurants = {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    address: this.templateAddress,
    specialities: this.templateSpecialities,
    details: this.templateDetails,
    booking: this.templateBookings
  };
```

In my HTML file i added this :

```
<input  
    formControlName="name" 
    id="name" 
    type="text" 
    class="form-control"
    placeholder={{selectedRestaurant.name}}>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i managed to fix my problem by adding a binding to the field that opens my edit-form:

```
<edit-form [selectedRestaurant] = "selectedRestaurant" *ngIf="editPressed"></edit-form>
```

When I click the "edit" button I am calling a method that is saving the value of the current object to the **selectedRestaurant**.

```
<button mat-icon-button (click)="editRestaurant(restaurant,!editPressed)">
```

In my restaurant.component i have this method that saves the restaurant for which i press the edit button and the boolean field is used to toggle the edit-form:

```
editRestaurant(passedRestaurant: Restaurants, isActivated:boolean): void {
        this.selectedRestaurant=passedRestaurant;
        this.editPressed=isActivated;

}
```

This is bound to an object in my edit-form component:

```
@Input('selectedRestaurant') selectedRestaurant: Restaurants = {
    id: 0,
    name: '',
    address: this.templateAddress,
    specialities: this.templateSpecialities,
    details: this.templateDetails,
    booking: this.templateBookings
  };
```

In my HTML file i added this :

```
    <input  
        formControlName="name" 
        id="name" 
        type="text" 
        class="form-control"
        placeholder={{selectedRestaurant.name}}>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about if you removed the place holder in the form controls? remove placeholder and check if this issue comes really for placeholder.

> I hope this issue not related with placeholder.it is related in unnecessary/missed provider. So please remove `String` in provider and check

```
providers: [
    HttpErrorHandler,
    HttpClientModule, //this is also not needed here
    String // remove this and try 
  ],
```

### Update:

Also provide the constructor parameters as nullable values ***or remove the constructor***

```
constructor(id?:String,name?:String,addressId?:String,specialitiesId?: String,detailsId?: String,bookingId?: String){
        this.id=id;
        this.name=name;
        this.addressId=addressId;
        this.specialitiesId=specialitiesId;
        this.detailsId=detailsId;
        this.bookingId=bookingId
    }
```

Comment: unnecessary providers i.e String / HttpClient - no change.
Also removed the placeholder from the form control - no change.

Comment: @BogdanMaceasa This `Can't resolve all parameters for String: (?).` error not related with placeholder. Did you removed those providers and check?

Comment: @BogdanMaceasa Also try **with** updated answer

Comment: I am controlling the values passed to the constructor, and also calling a constructor with static values so right now i don't think that I need the nullable check in the constructor. When I get passed the placeholder issue, I will move to also add nullables and other missing parts before actually connecting it to my POST service.

Comment: also tried removing the constructor - still the same error :

"main.ts:12 Error: Can't resolve all parameters for String: (?).
    at getUndecoratedInjectableFactory (core.js:11428)
    at injectableDefOrInjectorDefFactory (core.js:11418)
    at providerToFactory (core.js:11461)
    at providerToRecord (core.js:11448)
    at R3Injector.processProvider (core.js:11346)
    at core.js:11332
    at core.js:4129
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at deepForEach (core.js:4129)
    at R3Injector.processInjectorType (core.js:11332)"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
<input type="text" #input />
@ViewChild('input') input: ElementRef;
this.input.nativeElement.placeholder = 'placeholder text';
```

Comment: The constructor throws an error in the browser. 

  constructor(editedRestaurant: RestaurantsPost) {
   this.templateRestaurant = new RestaurantsPost(
      editedRestaurant.id,
      editedRestaurant.name,
      editedRestaurant.addressId,
      editedRestaurant.specialitiesId,
      editedRestaurant.detailsId,
      editedRestaurant.bookingId);
    this.input.nativeElement.placeholder = 'placeholder text'; // added this
    console.log(this.restaurantForm);

Error : main.ts:12 Error: Can't resolve all parameters for String: (?).

Answer (score -1):

I think the issue is here:

```
namePlaceholder:String="";
```

should be

```
namePlaceholder: string="";
```

Comment: This is rendered either way. However, any future changes I make to "namePlaceholder" are not updated in the placeholder field in my HTML. 
I have tried both primitive string and String object, they have the same outcome.